# Help interpreting count data GLMM using lme4 glmer and glmer.nb - Negative binomial versus Poisson

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, glmm

I have some questions regarding specification and interpretation of GLMMs. 3 questions are definitely statistical and 2 are more specifically about R. I am posting here because ultimately I think the issue is interpretation of GLMM results.

I am currently trying to fit a GLMM. I'm using US census data from the [Longitudinal Tract Database](https://s4.ad.brown.edu/projects/diversity/Researcher/ltdb.htm). My observations are census tracts. My dependent variable is the number of vacant housing units and I'm interested in the relationship between vacancy and socio-economic variables. The example here is simple, just using two fixed effects: percent non-white population (race) and median household income (class), plus their interaction. I would like to include two nested random effects: tracts within decades and decades, i.e. (decade/tract). I am considering these random in an effort to control for spatial (i.e. between tracts) and temporal (i.e. between decades) autocorrelation. However, I am interested in decade as a fixed effect also, so I am including it as a fixed factor also.

Since my independent variable is a non-negative integer count variable, I've been trying to fit poisson and negative binomial GLMMs. I am using the log of total housing units as an offset. This means coefficients are interpreted as the effect on vacancy rate, not total number of vacant houses.

I currently have results for a Poisson and a negative binomial GLMM estimated using glmer and glmer.nb from [lme4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/). The interpretation of coefficients makes sense to me based on my knowledge of the data and study area.

If you want the [data](https://github.com/samuel-walker/glmm-help/blob/master/LTDB_stackexchange.csv) and [script](https://github.com/samuel-walker/glmm-help/blob/master/script-crossvalidated.R) they are on my [Github](https://github.com/samuel-walker/). The script includes more of the descriptive investigations I did before building the models.

Here are my results:

## Poisson model

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: R_VAC ~ decade + P_NONWHT + a_hinc + P_NONWHT * a_hinc + offset(HU_ln) +      (1 | decade/TRTID10)
   Data: scaled.mydata

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 34520.1  34580.6 -17250.1  34500.1     3132 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.24211 -0.10799 -0.00722  0.06898  0.68129 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 TRTID10:decade (Intercept) 0.4635   0.6808  
 decade         (Intercept) 0.0000   0.0000  
Number of obs: 3142, groups:  TRTID10:decade, 3142; decade, 5

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     -3.612242   0.028904 -124.98  < 2e-16 ***
decade1980       0.302868   0.040351    7.51  6.1e-14 ***
decade1990       1.088176   0.039931   27.25  < 2e-16 ***
decade2000       1.036382   0.039846   26.01  < 2e-16 ***
decade2010       1.345184   0.039485   34.07  < 2e-16 ***
P_NONWHT         0.175207   0.012982   13.50  < 2e-16 ***
a_hinc          -0.235266   0.013291  -17.70  < 2e-16 ***
P_NONWHT:a_hinc  0.093417   0.009876    9.46  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) dc1980 dc1990 dc2000 dc2010 P_NONWHT a_hinc
decade1980  -0.693                                            
decade1990  -0.727  0.501                                     
decade2000  -0.728  0.502  0.530                              
decade2010  -0.714  0.511  0.517  0.518                       
P_NONWHT     0.016  0.007 -0.016 -0.015  0.006                
a_hinc      -0.023 -0.011  0.023  0.022 -0.009  0.221         
P_NONWHT:_h  0.155  0.035 -0.134 -0.129  0.003  0.155   -0.233
convergence code: 0
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00181132 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
```

## Negative binomial model

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: Negative Binomial(25181.5)  ( log )
Formula: R_VAC ~ decade + P_NONWHT + a_hinc + P_NONWHT * a_hinc + offset(HU_ln) +      (1 | decade/TRTID10)
   Data: scaled.mydata

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 34522.1  34588.7 -17250.1  34500.1     3131 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.24213 -0.10816 -0.00724  0.06928  0.68145 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 TRTID10:decade (Intercept) 4.635e-01 6.808e-01
 decade         (Intercept) 1.532e-11 3.914e-06
Number of obs: 3142, groups:  TRTID10:decade, 3142; decade, 5

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     -3.612279   0.028946 -124.79  < 2e-16 ***
decade1980       0.302897   0.040392    7.50 6.43e-14 ***
decade1990       1.088211   0.039963   27.23  < 2e-16 ***
decade2000       1.036437   0.039884   25.99  < 2e-16 ***
decade2010       1.345227   0.039518   34.04  < 2e-16 ***
P_NONWHT         0.175216   0.012985   13.49  < 2e-16 ***
a_hinc          -0.235274   0.013298  -17.69  < 2e-16 ***
P_NONWHT:a_hinc  0.093417   0.009879    9.46  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) dc1980 dc1990 dc2000 dc2010 P_NONWHT a_hinc
decade1980  -0.693                                            
decade1990  -0.728  0.501                                     
decade2000  -0.728  0.502  0.530                              
decade2010  -0.715  0.512  0.517  0.518                       
P_NONWHT     0.016  0.007 -0.016 -0.015  0.006                
a_hinc      -0.023 -0.011  0.023  0.022 -0.009  0.221         
P_NONWHT:_h  0.154  0.035 -0.134 -0.129  0.003  0.155   -0.233
```

## Poisson DHARMa tests

```
    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  simulationOutput$scaledResiduals
D = 0.044451, p-value = 8.104e-06
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

    DHARMa zero-inflation test via comparison to expected zeros with simulation under H0 = fitted model

data:  simulationOutput
ratioObsExp = 1.3666, p-value = 0.159
alternative hypothesis: more
```

## Negative binomial DHARMa tests

```
    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  simulationOutput$scaledResiduals
D = 0.04263, p-value = 2.195e-05
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

    DHARMa zero-inflation test via comparison to expected zeros with simulation under H0 = fitted model

data:  simulationOutput2
ratioObsExp = 1.376, p-value = 0.174
alternative hypothesis: more
```

## DHARMa plots

### Poisson

[image: Poisson model DHARMa plot]

### Negative binomial

[image: Negative binomial model DHARMa plot]

## Statistics questions

Since I am still figuring out GLMMs I am feeling insecure about specification and interpretation. I have some questions:

1. It appears my data do not support using a Poisson model and therefore I am better off with negative binomial. However, I consistently get warnings that my negative binomial models reach their iteration limit, even when I increase the maximum limit. "In theta.ml(Y, mu, weights = object@resp$weights, limit = limit,  :  iteration limit reached." This happens using quite a few different specifications (i.e. minimial and maximal models for both fixed and random effects). I have also tried removing outliers in my dependent (gross, I know!), since the top 1% of values are very much outliers (bottom 99% range from 0-1012, top 1% from 1013-5213). That didn't have any effect on iterations and very little effect on coefficients either. I don't include those details here. Coefficients between Poisson and negative binomial are also pretty similar. Is this lack of convergence a problem? Is the negative binomial model a good fit? I have also run the negative binomial model using [AllFit](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#troubleshooting) and not all optimizers throw this warning (bobyqa, Nelder Mead, and nlminbw did not).
2. The variance for my decade fixed effect is consistently very low or 0. I understand this could mean the model is overfit. Taking decade out of the fixed effects does increase the decade random effect variance to 0.2620 and doesn't have much of an effect on fixed effect coefficients. Is there anything wrong with leaving it in? I am fine interpreting it as simply not being needed to explain between observation variance.
3. Do these results indicate I should try zero-inflated models? DHARMa seems to suggest zero-inflation may not be the issue. If you think I should try anyway, see below.

## R questions

4. I would be willing to try zero-inflated models, but I am not sure which package impliments nested random effects for zero-inflated Poisson and negative binomial GLMMs. I would use glmmADMB to compare AIC with zero-inflated models, but it is restricted to a single random effect so doesn't work for this model. I could try MCMCglmm, but I do not know Bayesian statistics so that is also not attractive. Any other options?
5. Can I display exponentiated coefficients within summary(model), or do I have to do it outside summary as I've done here?

Comment: (2) is easy: having `decade` as both fixed and random does not make sense. Either have it as fixed and include only `(1 | decade:TRTID10)` as random (which is equivalent to `(1 | TRTID10)` assuming that your `TRTID10` does not have same levels for different decades), or remove it from the fixed effects. With only 4 levels you might be better of to have it fixed: the usual recommendation is to fit random effects if one has 5 levels or more.

Comment: Apart from that, your two plots appear identical.

Comment: Right, thanks @amoeba, that makes sense. Part of the issue _is_ that the plots appear very similar. The difference between my Poisson and negative binomial models appears small, but the negative binomial model reaches its iteration limit (even if it is set very high, e.g. 200,000). That is a warning, not an error, but I'm still not sure if I can trust the results.

Comment: Regarding the convergence warning - you said in (1) that you tried `bobyqa` optimizer and it did not produce any warning. What's the problem then? Just use `bobyqa`.

Comment: By the way, I don't understand why you say that "It appears my data do not support using a Poisson model".

Comment: Hi @amoeba, I can go with `bobyqa`, I was just concerned about the fact other optimizers didn't finish iterating. As in, might that indicate a poorly-specified model? Anyway, I'll see what happens when I change the random effects structure as per @prestevez answer below. Also I was leaning against Poisson due to the lack of equidispersion as per @prestevez table below, which I had previously calculated but not included in the post.

Comment: In my experience `bobyqa` converges better than the default optimizer (and I think I read somewhere that it is going to become default in the future versions of `lme4`). I don't think you need to worry about non-convergence with the default optimizer if it does converge with `bobyqa`.

Comment: @amoeba ok great, that is good to know. Thanks again!

Comment: You could plot the results based on various optimizers. If the results are consistent across optimizers, they would be more trustworthy. A function and a code-through is available at: https://pablobernabeu.github.io/2021/a-new-function-to-plot-convergence-diagnostics-from-lme4-allfit/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe there are some important problems to be addressed with your estimation.

From what I gathered by examining your data, your units are not geographically grouped, i.e. census tracts within counties. Thus, using tracts as a grouping factor is not appropriate to capture spatial heterogeneity as this means that you have the same number of individuals as groups (or to put another way, all your groups have only one observation each). Using a multilevel modelling strategy allows us to estimate individual-level variance, while controlling for between-group variance. Since your groups have only one individual each, your between-group variance is the same as your individual-level variance, thus defeating the purpose of the multilevel approach.

On the other hand, the grouping factor can represent repeated measurements over time. For example, in the case of a longitudinal study, an individual's "maths" scores may be recored yearly, thus we would have a yearly value for each student for n years (in this case, the grouping factor is the student as we have n number of observations "nested" within students). In your case, you have repeated measures of each census tract by `decade`. Thus, you could use your `TRTID10` variable as a grouping factor to capture "between decade variance". This leads to 3142 observations nested in 635 tracts, with approximately 4 and 5 observations per census tract.

As mentioned in a comment, using `decade` as a grouping factor is not very appropriate, as you have only around 5 decades for each census tract, and their effect can be better captured introducing `decade` as a covariate.

Second, to determine whether your data ought to be modelled using a poisson or negative binomial model (or a zero inflated approach). Consider the amount of overdispersion in your data. The fundamental characteristic of a Poisson distribution is equidispersion, meaning that the mean is equal to the variance of the distribution. Looking at your data, it is pretty clear that there is much overdispersion. Variances are much much greater than the means.

```
library(dplyr)    
 dispersionstats <- scaled.mydata %>%
 + group_by(decade) %>%
 + summarise(
 + means = mean(R_VAC),
 + variances = var(R_VAC),
 + ratio = variances/means)

##   dispersionstats
##   # A tibble: 5 x 5
##   decade     means variances     ratio 
##    <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> 
## 1   1970  45.43513   4110.89  90.47822 
## 2   1980 103.52365  17323.34 167.33707 
## 3   1990 177.68038  62129.65 349.67087 
## 4   2000 190.23150  91059.60 478.67784 
## 5   2010 247.68246 126265.60 509.78821
```

Nonetheless, to determine if the negative binomial is more appropriate statistically, a standard method is to do a likelihood ratio test between a Poisson and a negative binomial model, which suggests that the negbin is a better fit.

```
library(MASS)
library(lmtest)

modelformula <- formula(R_VAC ~ factor(decade) + P_NONWHT * a_hinc + offset(HU_ln))

poismodel <- glm(modelformula, data = scaled.mydata, family = "poisson")   
nbmodel <- glm.nb(modelformula, data = scaled.mydata)

lrtest(poismodel, nbmodel)

## Likelihood ratio test

##  Model 1: R_VAC ~ factor(decade) + P_NONWHT * a_hinc + offset(HU_ln)  
## Model 2: R_VAC ~ factor(decade) + P_NONWHT * a_hinc + offset(HU_ln)
##   #Df  LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
## 1   8 -154269
## 2   9  -17452  1 273634  < 2.2e-16 ***
##  ---
## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

After establishing this, a next test could consider whether the multilevel (mixed model) approach is warranted using similar approach, which suggests that the multilevel version provides a better fit. (A similar test could be used to compare a glmer fit assuming a poisson distribution to the glmer.nb object, as long as the models are otherwise the same.)

```
library(lme4)

glmmformula <- update(modelformula, . ~ . + (1|TRTID10))

nbglmm <- glmer.nb(glmmformula, data = scaled.mydata)

lrtest(nbmodel, nbglmm)

## Model 1: R_VAC ~ factor(decade) + P_NONWHT * a_hinc + offset(HU_ln)
## Model 2: R_VAC ~ factor(decade) + P_NONWHT + a_hinc + (1 | TRTID10) +
##     P_NONWHT:a_hinc + offset(HU_ln)
##   #Df LogLik Df Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
## 1   9 -17452
## 2  10 -17332  1 239.3  < 2.2e-16 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Regarding the estimates of the poisson and nb models they are actually expected to be very similar to each other, with the main distinction being the standard errors, ie if overdispersion is present, the poisson model tends to provide biased standard errors. Taking your data as an example:

```
poissonglmm <- glmer(glmmformula, data = scaled.mydata)
summary(poissonglmm)

## Random effects:
##  Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
## TRTID10 (Intercept) 0.2001   0.4473
## Number of obs: 3142, groups:  TRTID10, 635

## Fixed effects:
##                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
## (Intercept)        -2.876013   0.020602 -139.60   <2e-16 ***
## factor(decade)1980  0.092597   0.007602   12.18   <2e-16 ***
## factor(decade)1990  0.903543   0.007045  128.26   <2e-16 ***
## factor(decade)2000  0.854821   0.006913  123.65   <2e-16 ***
## factor(decade)2010  0.986126   0.006723  146.67   <2e-16 ***
## P_NONWHT           -0.125500   0.014007   -8.96   <2e-16 ***
## a_hinc             -0.107335   0.001480  -72.52   <2e-16 ***
## P_NONWHT:a_hinc     0.160937   0.003117   51.64   <2e-16 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

summary(nbglmm)
## Random effects:
##  Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
##  TRTID10 (Intercept) 0.09073  0.3012
## Number of obs: 3142, groups:  TRTID10, 635

## Fixed effects:
##                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
## (Intercept)        -2.797861   0.056214  -49.77  < 2e-16 ***
## factor(decade)1980  0.118588   0.039589    3.00  0.00274 **
## factor(decade)1990  0.903440   0.038255   23.62  < 2e-16 ***
## factor(decade)2000  0.843949   0.038172   22.11  < 2e-16 ***
## factor(decade)2010  1.068025   0.037376   28.58  < 2e-16 ***
## P_NONWHT            0.020012   0.089224    0.22  0.82253
## a_hinc             -0.129094   0.008109  -15.92  < 2e-16 ***
## P_NONWHT:a_hinc     0.149223   0.018967    7.87 3.61e-15 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Notice how the coefficient estimates are all very similar, the main difference being only the significance of one of your covariates, as well as the difference in the random effects variance, which suggests that the unit-level variance captured by the overdispersion parameter in the nb model (the `theta` value in the glmer.nb object) captures some of the between tract variance captured by the random effects.

Regarding exponentiated coefficients (and associated confidence intervals), you can use the following:

```
fixed <- fixef(nbglmm)
confnitfixed <- confint(nbglmm, parm = "beta_", method = "Wald") # Beware: The Wald method is less accurate but much, much faster.

# The exponentiated coefficients are also known as Incidence Rate Ratios (IRR)
IRR <- exp(cbind(fixed, confintfixed)
IRR
##                         fixed      2.5 %     97.5 %
## (Intercept)        0.06094028 0.05458271 0.06803835
## factor(decade)1980 1.12590641 1.04184825 1.21674652
## factor(decade)1990 2.46807856 2.28979339 2.66024515
## factor(decade)2000 2.32553168 2.15789585 2.50619029
## factor(decade)2010 2.90962703 2.70410073 3.13077444
## P_NONWHT           1.02021383 0.85653208 1.21517487
## a_hinc             0.87889172 0.86503341 0.89297205
## P_NONWHT:a_hinc    1.16093170 1.11856742 1.20490048
```

Final thoughts, regarding zero inflation. There is no multilevel implementation (at least that I am aware of) of a zero inflated poisson or negbin model that allows you to specify an equation for zero inflated component of the mixture. the `glmmADMB` model lets you estimate a constant zero inflation parameter. An alternative approach would be to use the `zeroinfl` function in the `pscl` package, though this does not support multilevel models. Thus, you could compare the fit of a single level negative binomial, to the single level zero inflated negative binomial. Chances are that if zero inflation is not significant for single level models, it is likely that it would not be significant for the multilevel specification.

### Addendum

If you are concerned about spatial autocorrelation, you could control for this using some form of geographical weighted regression (though I believe this uses point data, not areas). Alternatively, you could group your census tracts by an additional grouping factor (states, counties) and include this as a random effect. Lastly, and I am not sure if this is entirely feasible, it may be possible to incorporate spatial dependence using, for example, the average count of `R_VAC` in first order neighbours as a covariate. In any case, prior to such approaches, it would be sensible to determine if spatial autocorrelation is indeed present (using Global Moran's I, LISA tests, and similar approaches).

Comment: `brms` can fit zero-inflated negative binomial models with random effects.

Comment: @prestevez and @Andrew, this is super useful! It has clarified a lot of issues I was having. Thanks for taking the time to walk me through it. I'm going to try fitting a zinb mixed model from `brms` and compare that to the glmer.nb model as outlined above. I'll also try including census-defined place (basically municipality, ~170 groups) as a grouping factor for the random effects (only 5 counties in the data, so I won't use that). I'll also test for spatial autocorrelation of residuals using Global Moran's I. I'll report back when I've done that.

Comment: @AndrewM, thanks for the info! I was not aware of brms and not familiar with bayesian statistics in general, though I am now quite interested to look into it.

Comment: @SamuelWalker Glad it was useful! Municipality sounds like a good choice (I am not familiar with US census data so I suggested counties without really knowing if they would be appropriate). Regarding comparing glmer.nb fits to a brms object though, I am not sure whay would be the best way to compare them, as I am not familiar with bayesian statistics. Good luck!

Comment: @prestevez ah, of course `brms` is Bayesian. I am also not familiar with it and assume the models are not comparable. I might still take a look at it.

Comment: @SamuelWalker a potential alternative might be to fit both standard and zero inflated negbin models using `brms` and compare them.